# How to elegantly drop unnecessary elements in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

I have an ndarray of shape `[batch_size, seq_len, num_features]`. However, some of elements in the end of the sequential dimension is not necessary, and therefore I want to drop them and merge the sequential dimension into the batch dimension. For example, the ndarray `a` I want to manipulate is

```py
batch_size = 2
seq_len = 3
num_features = 1
a = np.random.randn(batch_size, seq_len, num_features)
mask = np.ones((batch_size, seq_len), dtype=np.bool)
mask[0][1:] = 0
mask[1][2:] = 0
"""
>>> a = [[[-0.3908401 ]
  [ 0.89686512]
  [ 0.07594243]]

 [[-0.12256737]
  [-1.00838131]
  [ 0.56543754]]]
mask=[[ True False False]
 [ True  True False]]
"""
```

where `mask` is used to indicate whether the elements in `a` is useful. I can get what I want using the following code

```py
res = []
for seq, m in zip(a, mask):
    res.append(seq[:sum(m)])
np.concatenate(res, axis=0)
"""
>>>array([[0.08676509],
       [0.47162315],
       [0.98070665]])
"""
```

I'm wondering if there is a more elegant way to do this in numpy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is what your asking but the results look fine

`res = a[mask]`

Comment: Just to add to this answer, this works because the 2 dimension you want to join are the first 2. To be more generic when doing this operation on a (d1,...,dn) array with a for example (d3,d4) mask you should do something like   res = a[:,:,mask]

Comment: Thanks for your extremely concise answer : )

Answer (score 0):

Since dimensions related to batch and seq are going to be merged, you could reshape both `a` and `mask` to 2D array of shape `(batch_size * seq_len, num_features)`.

Next, simply filter important samples using boolean index. See the code:

```
mask2d = mask.reshape(-1) # or mask.ravel()
a2d = a.reshape(-1, num_features)
result = a2d[mask2d]
```